# how to view saved passwords with root

Tags: adb, shell, password

How do I get the saved wifi passwords from my android kitkat phone. It is rooted and I have the adb tool. How do I do this? I know that I can download stuff to do it but I do not want to download any application as my device has no more storage. What other options do I have? I have looked around but I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

first, if using windows, go the the folder containing adb.exe. then shift right click on the folder and select `open cmd here`. then type `adb devices` to check is the device has developer options on. type `adb root` .then type `adb shell`. if the `$` sign changes to `#` then it is now in root mode. type `cd /data/misc/wifi`. then type `cat wpa_supplicant.conf`. VOILA!

Comment: Keep in mind that some manufacturers (Samsung) usually encrypt those passwords. Good luck with those.